# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' python

Tags: python

```
#!/C:\Users\Yue\Desktop\

import re
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

output = open("udp_data","w")
sum = defaultdict(list)

with open("DNS","r") as input:
    ip = []
    port = []

    for line in input:

            if re.match("(.*)Internet(.*)",line):
                    ip.append(line.split("Src: ",1)[1])

            if re.match("(.*)User(.*)",line):
                     port.append(line)

count = 0                          
for y in ip:
    if y in sum:
        sum[y].append(port[count])
    else:
        sum[y]= port[count]

    count += 1

pprint (sum)
```

Could anyone help me with this error, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'? I have no idea why it keeps telling me I cannot append str to a list which I defined for dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you've got does not say that you cannot append a `str` to a list. It's saying your string does not have an `append` method..

In your code `port` is a list of strings. 
On line:

```
sum[y] = port[count]
```

... you are assigning the element `port[count]`, which is of type `str` to `sum[y]`. After that you are trying with ...

```
sum[y].append(port[count])
```

... to append an item to your before assigned string - At this point sum[y]` is a string and not a list.